# How to check if a rigidbody is moving?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i want to check if a rigidbody is moving and ive tried multiple of things and it doesnt seem to work.

Im adding my code snippet below but the Update function is basically triggered when a gameobject lands in a certain area.  at that point, i access a rigidbody on a rope to see if its moving.  For the snippet im using the IsSleeping function but it doenst work.  anyone know how i can check once a gameobject lands on a specific area to check if it stopped moving.

```
void Start()
{
    checkSleeping = false;
    joint = player.transform.Find("Joint 0").gameObject;
    jointRB = joint.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    Debug.Log("Found Him");
}


void Update()
{
    if (checkSleeping == true)
    {
        SleepingKonyaku();
    }
}

void OnTriggerStay2D (Collider2D col)
{
   if (col.tag == "Player" )
   {
        checkSleeping = true;
   }
}

void OnTriggerExit2D (Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.tag == "Player")
    {
        checkSleeping = false;
    }
}

void SleepingKonyaku ()
{        

    if(jointRB.IsSleeping())
    {
         Invoke ("RestartLevel", 2f);
         Debug.Log ("sleeping baby!!");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Not Sleeping");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something is considered to be moving when it has a non-zero velocity. So do that: check whether the magnitude (length) of the `Rigidbody`'s velocity is 0 or at least close to it. For some extra performance, you can use `sqrMagnitude` instead of `magnitude`: this does not involve taking the square root of a value, which is a relatively slow process.

Comment: Ive tried using jointRB.velocity.sqrmagnitute == 0f  but that doesnt seem to work.  Do you think i should try grabbing the position of the gameobject instead of the rigidbody of a joint in the object to see if it stopped moving?

Comment: what im noticing is that, once the gameobject enters the zone where it looks to see if the gameobject is moving.  it triggers it right away, and the next level is loaded.  I dont understand why it would trigger true to a rigidbody.IsSleeping() when i can visibly see it flying and bouncing around the platform.